# How many different paths from origin to $(4,4)$ if you can't cross $y = x$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Assuming you can only go right 1 step or up 1 step, and you're trying to get from the origin to $(4,4)$ or any $(n,n)$ or $(m,n)$, what is an algorithm to help you determine the number of paths possible without crossing $y=x$?

I can do it just by experimenting and drawing, but I was told it's better to use an inductive proof.

I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Intuitively, I know that it's the number of paths from the origin to $(n,n)$, which is $\binom{2n}{n}$ minus the number of paths that cross the $y=x$ line.

The base case is, for example, $(1,1)$. Theres two possible paths, and one crosses $y=x$. But what next?

Comment: Have you heard of Catalan Numbers?

Comment: @JMoravitz we haven't covered those yet :(

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof

Comment: The inclusion–exclusion principle should help to get the number of paths which cross the diagonal.

Comment: If you don´t give a reply we cannot help you.

Comment: @callculus i think i got it now, thanks!

Comment: @MelanieSanders I´m pleased to hear that.